# How to write to text file which is situated into project directory?

Tags: c#, file, file-io, directory

I use WriteAllText function to write some info to txt. I call it from App_Code/MyFolder/MyClass.cs and my file is situated into Files folder that is on the same level with App_Code. How my path have looking?

```
File.WriteAllText("../../Files/test.txt", "Done");
```

Comment: your question is not clear, can you rephrase it

Comment: Please be more specific about what errors you are receiving & what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok. I want to write some info to my txt file. The function that do it is situated in [Root]/App_Code/MyFolder/MyClass.cs My txt file is situated in [root]/Files and I can't write something using my path which I write below in the post.

Comment: @Matt-Hensley Static method WriteAllText write nothing to my file using this path.

Answer (score 0):

If I have to do something like this I will first of all get current directory using 
    System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
and then go up using 
    Directory.GetParent Method 
to get desired directory where I have to write file.